# C - How to split a linked list with struct type data

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I have a problem that require Splitting a singly linked list into 2 part with a function: Split(n1, n2) where n1 = position of the element, n2 is number of elements to be split. I've managed to come up with an algorithm and a Testing program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

 struct Node
{
int value;
struct Node *next;
 };

int push_front( struct Node **head, int value )
{
struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
int success = new_node != NULL;

if ( success )
{
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->next = *head;

    *head = new_node;
}

return success;
}

void display( const struct Node *head )
{
for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
{
    printf( "%d -> ", head->value );
}

//puts( "null" );
}

struct ListPair
{
struct Node *head1;
struct Node *head2;
};


struct ListPair split( struct Node **head, size_t pos, size_t n )
{
struct ListPair p = { .head1 = NULL, .head2 = NULL };

struct Node **current1 = &p.head1;
struct Node **current2 = &p.head2;

for ( size_t i = 0; *head != NULL && i != pos; i++ )
{
    *current2 = *head;
    *head = ( *head )->next;
    ( *current2 )->next = NULL;
    current2 = &( *current2 )->next;
}

while ( *head != NULL && n-- )
{
    *current1 = *head;
    *head = ( *head )->next;
    ( *current1 )->next = NULL;
    current1 = &( *current1 )->next;
}

while ( *head != NULL )
{
    *current2 = *head;
    *head = ( *head )->next;
    ( *current2 )->next = NULL;
    current2 = &( *current2 )->next;
}

return p;
}


int main(void) 
{
const size_t N = 15;
struct Node *head = NULL;

srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );  

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    push_front( &head, rand() % N );
}

display( head );
putchar( '\n' );

struct ListPair p = split( &head, 6, 3  );

display( head );
display( p.head1 );
display( p.head2 );

return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
12 -> 14 -> 3 -> 0 -> 12 -> 5 -> 4 -> 0 -> 2 -> 14 -> 1 -> 0 -> 6 -> 0 -> 5 -> null

null
5 -> 4 -> 0 -> 2 -> 14 -> null
12 -> 14 -> 3 -> 0 -> 12 -> 1 -> 0 -> 6 -> 0 -> 5 -> null
```

But don't know how to implement the above into my linked list, which is:

```
typedef struct address_t
{
char name[30];
char storage[5];
char screen[5];
int price;
} address;


typedef address elementtype;
typedef struct node node;
typedef struct node{
elementtype element;
node *next;
};

node *root, *cur, *prev;
```

Please help :(

Comment: You showed the code that I provided for some question, What is the problem> After creating a node with malloc fill its data members with required values.

Comment: I think first you have to write your own code. After that if you have any issue then ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

As far as I understand the question you simply want to remove a sublist from a single linked list e.g. the `list = el1 -> el2 -> el5 -> el6 -> el3 -> null`. When you call `split(list, 2, 2)` the result will be two lists `list and list1` with `list = el1 -> el2 -> el3 -> null` and `list1 = el5 -> el6 -> null`.

But what is not really clear is what the actual problem is you are facing, and what have you tried so far to make it work?

## Answer

From how I read the question it is not really important, how the content of each list element looks like. So why don't you just take your `struct Node` from the example and replace the field `int value` by `address value` like the following:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[30];
  char storage[5];
  char screen[5];
  int price;
} address;

struct Node
{
  address value;
  struct Node *next;
 };
```

There are a few issues in your code you might want to change.
 1.  Your split function sets the passed in pointer `head` to NULL. This might not be wanted behavior
 2. You are returning a struct from `split(...)`. Since everything in C is passed around by value you might consider passing a (double-)pointer to `split(...)` as well and put the resulted `ListPair` in there, because then the `ListPair` has not to be copied when returning from the function
 3.  Normally you would not use a `_t` for the struct name but not for the typedef itself.
 4. You typedef the struct `address_t` and typedef the type with `elementtype`, but never used `address`
 5. You have a typedef, that does not have a name

```
typedef struct node{
 elementtype element;
 node *next;
};
```

Just remove the `typedef` in that line, because you already did a typedef one line before.

Comment: He already showed code that splits a list in two lists. Ge does not know how to fill fields of his data structure then it has more than one field shown in the provided code.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I am not yet allowed to write comments below questions...